# Using atom text editor with the vim-mode package, how do I view commands in command mode?

Tags: atom-editor

I just started using atom and I want to be able to see the commands I'm typing (i.e. ':' some command, but unlike in vim where you see them at the bottom of the window I don't see them in atom. Anyone know where/if they appear?

Answer (score 1):

The "Key Binding Resolver" should show you what you want. You can get there by hitting `Cmd`+`.`

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience it does not show the command, but does work in some instances like search (:?) or (/). This is shown under the text editor main window.